# how to solve the 413 entity too large in Bean Stack Configuration for ktor server?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, ktor, ktorm

After deploying the app on beanstack I am getting the 413 Entity too large Exception. I know the reason of this Exception but I don't know where can I need to configure this client request body max size in ktor project or Beanstack.
I tried to increase the size on client request body and added the custom configuration in the `.platform/nginx/conf.d/myConfig.conf` and `.ebextensions/nginx/conf.d/proxy.conf` files but didn’t get any luck.

Note: It is working fine in local but getting this issue after deploying...

Answer (score 0):

`myConfig.cong`is an **incorrect** config file for configuring  nginx. The correct files have extension `*.conf` as described in [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/platforms-linux-extend.html).

Comment: Sorry, Typo mistake. That's actually conf.

Comment: @anas If you make such mistakes in the question, its likely you have some typos in your EB files as well. Thus you have to double check all of them.

Comment: There is only 1 line in this file `client_max_body_size 100M;`. Already checked there is no typo issue in there. @Marcin